# htaccess rewrite rule giving 500 server error

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I know there are tons of posts on here already describing this exact same problem, but I've been looking through them and trying the different solutions to no avail.

I'm attempting to rewrite a URL with a query string at the end and write the value of the query string into the end of the URL. I've tried numerous patterns from numerous answers, but I keep getting either no change in the URL or a 500 Internal Server error.

Here's my htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/oh/shit/you/broke/the/internet
RewriteRule ^oh/shit/you/broke/the/internet$ /404.php [L]
RewriteRule ^email/([^/]+)/?$ /email/?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

I want http://domain.com/email/?name=blah to be rewritten to http://domain.com/email/blah

What am I missing here?

================

## EDIT:

After looking through the logs, I'm seeing a lot of the following errors:

```
Invalid command '^email/([^/]+)/?$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Invalid command '^/email/([^/]+)/?$', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
File does not exist: /home/username/domain.com/email/blah
```

Here's the full htaccess file after including the fix:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.com/oh/shit/you/broke/the/internet
RewriteRule ^oh/shit/you/broke/the/internet$ /404.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+email/?\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /email/%1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^email/([^/]+)/?$ /email/?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad syntax. Your code doesn't have `RewriteRule` keyword.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options All -Indexes

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+email/?\?name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /email/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^email/([^/]+)/?$ /email/?name=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: Ok, I did, indeed, forget the RewriteRule for some strange reason. However, now it's back to simply not modifying the URL at all... Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, it's rewriting the URL correctly now, but still giving a 500 IS error. I'm not even sure all this headache is worth it if such a simple task takes this amount of troubleshooting! lol

Comment: Rules are perfectly fine now. You might have some other conflicting rule/code now causing 500. Read your Apache error.lgo for actual reason of 500

Comment: I've updated the question with the 3 errors I see in large numbers in the error log... The last of which is the most recent. So I'm assuming it's actually looking for the /email/blah subdirectory (which doesn't exist)

Comment: If you enter `http://domain.com/email/blah` in your browser what happens? Do you have any other code in this .htaccess?

Comment: I get a 500 IS error if I try to go directly to that link. Also I have a 404 document handler in the htacess file, but I'm not sure how that might be affecting this. I'll edit the question to include the full htaccess file text, though.

Comment: I forgot stack's comments don't allow line breaks... The full htaccess is updated in the question. (although the last line is still the original pattern I had for question integrity) My actual file includes your fix verbatim.

Comment: Oh not in comments, add it in your question.

Comment: ok comment your `ErrorDocument` line and make sure this is placed in `DocumentRoot` of your website Also is `email` is a sub-dir or a file?

Comment: email is an actual sub-directory with an index.php file in it.

Comment: Ok, I deleted the error document handler and its redirect completely. Still getting a 500 IS error.

Comment: Is this .haccess placed in `DocumentRoot` of your website? Is there any other .htaccess in email directory?

Comment: Quick question: Is a subdomain like `something.domain.com` still considered the root of the website? I'm assuming it is, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: Well I don't know your setup to answer that with surety. What is full URL to access `email/index.php`?

Comment: the user associated with this site has a directory listing that looks like this: `home -> user -> subdomain.domain.com`. Whereas the actual top level domain is under a different user entirely.

Comment: So this .htaccess is in `/home/user/subdomain.domain.com` folder I believe and you are accessing email as `http://subdomain.domain.com/email/?name=foo` Is that correct?

Comment: You sir, are a god among mere mortals.

Comment: I'm terribly sorry to have wasted nearly an hour of your time on something that probably could've been answered much quicker had I written my question more concisely.

Comment: Oh you're most welcome, glad it worked out for you. No need to be sorry at all. Just a hint for future questions that by providing as much info as possible upfront you will only help yourself by getting best answers. Cheers :)